# Passing object references between modules

Tags: javascript

I am rather new to javascript and trying to learn some of the best practices.  I am unclear as to why I can't access the ctx reference in the following code.  The log outputs a context2d reference from myApp.init().  Can I not expose a private object variable in the return statement of the myApp module?  I thought I was beginning to understand the basics of this language but am getting frustrated by this seemingly simple concept.  Thanks for your help.

```
window.onload = function () {
    myApp.init();
    console.log(myApp.ctx);        // logs undefined
};

var myApp = (function () {    

    var canvas,
        ctx,
        init = function () {
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            console.log(ctx);        // logs valid context2d object
        };

    return {
        init : init,
        ctx  : ctx
    };

}());

myApp.board = (function () {

    var ctx = myApp.ctx;

    return {
        ctx : function () { console.log(ctx); }   // logs undefined
    };

}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `init()` for `ctx` to be defined. However, by that point, it's too late, since myApp contains the original value of ctx.

You have exactly the same problem with `var ctx = myApp.ctx;`. That gets the value of the ctx when `board` is defined. It won't change if `myApp.ctx` changes.

---

This should work:

```
var myApp = new function () {
    var canvas;

    this.init = function () {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        console.log(this.ctx);        // logs valid context2d object
    };
};

myApp.board = new function () {
    this.ctx = function () { console.log(myApp.ctx); }
};
```

By using the `new` keyword, the functions become constructors (and are invoked immediately) - `this` refers to the object being created.

Comment: Thank, you this worked well.  Is this considered a "best practice"?  I've read some not-so-kind things about the new keyword.